# C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\*.cs could not be found

Tags: content-editor

I deleted all the files from the temp directory (`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp`) as my local instance was loading too slow.
And now the `Content Editor` doesn't load.

I tried deploying all the files into the instance, restarted the system and loading the CMS in incognito, with no luck.

The Launchpad loads fine though.

> ERROR Application error. Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
> Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was
> thrown. Source: System.Web    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message:
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source:
> mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
> Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
> Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs
> e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerException Message: Source
> file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\yizcraub.0.cs' could not be found Source: File:
> , line 0    at
> Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.AssertResults(String
> sourceFile, CompilerResults results)    at
> Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String sourceFile,
> String code, String assemblyFile, StringCollection
> referencedAssemblies)    at
> Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.Compile(String code,
> StringCollection referencedAssemblies)    at
> Sitecore.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCompiler.SourceToMemory(String code,
> StringCollection referencedAssemblies)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.BuildControlAssembly(XmlNode
> fileNode, String& assemblyKey, String& assemblyFile)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.GetControlAssembly(String
> controlName, String& assemblyKey)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.ResolveType(String
> controlName, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlSource.GetControlType(String
> namespacePrefix, String controlName, String mode, Boolean
> includeDynamicTypes)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControlType(String
> controlName, String mode, Boolean includeDynamicTypes)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.GetControl(Control parent,
> String controlName, String mode, Object[] properties,
> AllowGenericControl allowGeneric)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.LayoutGridBuilder.BuildDevice(GridPanel grid,
> LayoutDefinition layout, DeviceItem deviceItem)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.LayoutGridBuilder.BuildGrid(Control parent)
> at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.LayoutField.OnLoad(EventArgs
> e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
> System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.AddControl(Control parent, Control
> control, String placeholder)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.AddEditorControl(Control
> parent, Control editor, Field field, Boolean hasRibbon, Boolean
> readOnly, String value)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderField(Control
> parent, Field field, Item fieldType, Boolean readOnly, String value)
> at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderField(Control
> parent, Field field, Item fieldType, Boolean readOnly)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderField(Control
> parent, Field field, Boolean readOnly)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderSection(Section
> section, Control parent, Boolean readOnly)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderSections(Control
> parent, Sections sections, Boolean readOnly)    at (Object , Object )
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
> Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
> PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
> pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArgs
> args, Control parent)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item
> item, Item root, Control editorsContainer, Boolean showEditor)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item
> folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update()
> at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs
> e)

[image]

Comment: Does your application have the AppIdentity and IIS User permission?

Comment: Try to provide apppool permission on website folder.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal But this is an existing site which was working fine. Is this step still needed?

Comment: @Qwerty edit your question with stack trace as text

Answer (score -2):

This resolved the issue for me.

In `IIS Manager`, select the Application for your site.

In `Advanced settings", change the` Identity`.

In my case, it was "Built-in account" which was set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity".

I changed it to "LocalSystem", recycled the app pool and now the Content Editor loads fine.

Changing it back to "ApplicationPoolIdentity", resulted in the same error again. So I left it with "LocalSystem".

[image]

Comment: You need to provide apt permission instead of using this. If you have another instance running, you can compare and provide the same permission. This should ideally be the last option in my view.

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay You could be right. But as I mentioned, when I change it back to "ApplicationPoolIdentity", it gives the same error. I need to try it after a system restart.